# How to get min() data in an hour/half an hour after use pandas mask in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to filter out inner data in my large data frame(1400,000 rows).
This is a very short and easy version of sample data,

```
a      b        c       dt                   e
35   0.1      234   2020/6/15 14:27:00       0
1    0.1      554   2020/6/15 15:28:00       1
2    0.2      654   2020/6/15 16:29:00       0
23   0.4      2345  2020/6/15 17:26:00       0
34   0.8      245   2020/6/15 18:25:00       0
8    0.9      123   2020/6/15 18:26:00       0
7    0.1      22    2020/6/15 18:27:00       0
2    0.3      99    2020/6/15 18:28:00       0
219  0.2      17    2020/6/15 19:26:00       0
```

The result should look like `SQL query` as below:

```
select * from table where (a > 10 and a < 25) or b > 0.2 or c > 500 and e == 0
```

So I use `mask = (df['a'].lt(25) & df['a'].gt(10)) | df['b'].gt(0.2) | df['c'].gt(500) df[mask] & df['e'].eq(0)`, can I keep only one row such as df.c.min() between '2020/6/15 18:00:00' and '2020/6/15 19:00:00', we need the data under that conditon, but there are many dirty data, how to keep the lowest data in an hour or half an hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
# masking the first set of conditions:
mask = (df['a'].lt(25) & df['a'].gt(10) ) | df['b'].gt(0.2) | df['c'].gt(500)
mask = mask & df['e'].eq(0)
df = df[mask]

# select rows with min `c` values by 30 mins
c_min = df.groupby(df['dt'].dt.floor('30min'))['c'].idxmin()

# final df
df = df.loc[c_min]
```

Output:

```
    a    b     c                  dt  e
2   2  0.2   654 2020-06-15 16:29:00  0
3  23  0.4  2345 2020-06-15 17:26:00  0
7   2  0.3    99 2020-06-15 18:28:00  0
```

Comment: Hi, I got an error of `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`

Comment: Do a `df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt'])` prior to calculation of `c_min`.

Comment: Why are you so patient and excellent!!!!!!! You saved my day again and again, thank you so so so much!

Comment: we need a 1 or 0 column on orginal df, if I want to use `df['x'] = mask.astype(int)`, can I still use this?

Comment: I always got an error of `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`

Comment: hey,  do you know how to add a new column without Length Value error if match where/mask condition after groupby in python/pandas?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62680785/how-to-add-a-new-column-without-length-value-error-if-match-where-mask-condition