# How to add a new column without Length Value error if match where/mask condition after groupby in python/pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to filter out inner data in my large data frame(1400,000 rows).
This is a very short and easy version of sample data,

```
a      b        c       dt                   e
35   0.1      234   2020/6/15 14:27:00       0
1    0.1      554   2020/6/15 15:28:00       1
2    0.2      654   2020/6/15 16:29:00       0
23   0.4      2345  2020/6/15 17:26:00       0
34   0.8      245   2020/6/15 18:25:00       0
8    0.9      123   2020/6/15 18:26:00       0
7    0.1      22    2020/6/15 18:27:00       0
2    0.3      99    2020/6/15 18:28:00       0
219  0.2      17    2020/6/15 19:26:00       0
```

The result should look like `SQL query` as below:

```
select * from table where (a > 10 and a < 25) or b > 0.2 or c > 500 and e == 0
```

So I use `mask = (df['a'].lt(25) & df['a'].gt(10)) | df['b'].gt(0.2) | df['c'].gt(500) df[mask] & df['e'].eq(0)`, we have to keep only one row such as `df.c.min()` between '2020/6/15 18:00:00' and '2020/6/15 19:00:00',

to get the lowest data of half an hour, we do something like this:

```
# masking the first set of conditions:
mask = (df['a'].lt(25) & df['a'].gt(10) ) | df['b'].gt(0.2) | df['c'].gt(500)
mask = mask & df['e'].eq(0)
df = df[mask]

# select rows with min `c` values by 30 mins
c_min = df.groupby(df['dt'].dt.floor('30min'))['c'].idxmin()

# final df
df = df.loc[c_min]
```

Output:

```
    a    b     c                  dt  e
2   2  0.2   654 2020-06-15 16:29:00  0
3  23  0.4  2345 2020-06-15 17:26:00  0
7   2  0.3    99 2020-06-15 18:28:00  0
```

The output is what we need, but the problem is we have to add a new column to an original data frame(140,0000 rows) , if match this df[mask] condition, let c == 1, else let c==0,

because groupby(df['dt']) will drop some data, the below code become will get an error of `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`

```
df['c'] = mask.astype(int)
```

Comment: assign it before `df = df[mask]`. That is `df['c'] = mask.astype(int); df = df[mask]`

Comment: I got an error of 'A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df_temp['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df_temp['dt'])'

Answer (score 0):

If you only want a new column with the values that match with mask, as @Quang Hoang said, you could try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
s_e='''
a      b        c       dt                   e
35   0.1      234   2020/6/15 14:27:00       0
1    0.1      554   2020/6/15 15:28:00       1
2    0.2      654   2020/6/15 16:29:00       0
23   0.4      2345  2020/6/15 17:26:00       0
34   0.8      245   2020/6/15 18:25:00       0
8    0.9      123   2020/6/15 18:26:00       0
7    0.1      22    2020/6/15 18:27:00       0
2    0.3      99    2020/6/15 18:28:00       0
219  0.2      17    2020/6/15 19:26:00       0
'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s_e), sep='\s\s+', parse_dates=[3], engine='python')
print(df)
# masking the first set of conditions:
mask = (df['a'].lt(25) & df['a'].gt(10) ) | df['b'].gt(0.2) | df['c'].gt(500)
mask = mask & df['e'].eq(0)

#Quang Hoang recomendation:
df['indicator'] = mask.astype(int) 

print(df)
```

Output:

```
df
     a    b     c                  dt  e  indicator
0   35  0.1   234 2020-06-15 14:27:00  0          0
1    1  0.1   554 2020-06-15 15:28:00  1          0
2    2  0.2   654 2020-06-15 16:29:00  0          1
3   23  0.4  2345 2020-06-15 17:26:00  0          1
4   34  0.8   245 2020-06-15 18:25:00  0          1
5    8  0.9   123 2020-06-15 18:26:00  0          1
6    7  0.1    22 2020-06-15 18:27:00  0          0
7    2  0.3    99 2020-06-15 18:28:00  0          1
8  219  0.2    17 2020-06-15 19:26:00  0          0
```

If you want to indicate only the rows that match with the mask and also with min `c` values by 30 mins, you could try:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
s_e='''
a      b        c       dt                   e
35   0.1      234   2020/6/15 14:27:00       0
1    0.1      554   2020/6/15 15:28:00       1
2    0.2      654   2020/6/15 16:29:00       0
23   0.4      2345  2020/6/15 17:26:00       0
34   0.8      245   2020/6/15 18:25:00       0
8    0.9      123   2020/6/15 18:26:00       0
7    0.1      22    2020/6/15 18:27:00       0
2    0.3      99    2020/6/15 18:28:00       0
219  0.2      17    2020/6/15 19:26:00       0
'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s_e), sep='\s\s+', parse_dates=[3], engine='python')
print(df)
# masking the first set of conditions:
mask = (df['a'].lt(25) & df['a'].gt(10) ) | df['b'].gt(0.2) | df['c'].gt(500)
mask = mask & df['e'].eq(0)
df['indicator'] = [0]*len(df)

temp = df[mask] 
#select rows with min `c` values by 30 mins
c_min = temp.groupby(temp['dt'].dt.floor('30min'))['c'].idxmin()

# final df
df.loc[c_min,'indicator']=1
print(df)
```

Output:

```
df
     a    b     c                  dt  e  indicator
0   35  0.1   234 2020-06-15 14:27:00  0          0
1    1  0.1   554 2020-06-15 15:28:00  1          0
2    2  0.2   654 2020-06-15 16:29:00  0          1
3   23  0.4  2345 2020-06-15 17:26:00  0          1
4   34  0.8   245 2020-06-15 18:25:00  0          0
5    8  0.9   123 2020-06-15 18:26:00  0          0
6    7  0.1    22 2020-06-15 18:27:00  0          0
7    2  0.3    99 2020-06-15 18:28:00  0          1
8  219  0.2    17 2020-06-15 19:26:00  0          0
```

Comment: I got an error of 'A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df_temp['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df_temp['dt'])'

Comment: With which option of the answer do you get that?

Comment: I have to add that row, or I will get AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: I don't understand you... in which line the error occurs? which option of the answer did you use? Could you attach an screenshot of the error you are getting?